# Ubuntu Mate 16.04.1 Live USB Freezing

Tags: software-installation, live-usb, ubuntu-mate, powerpc

Help! I made an Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 Live USB for a PowerBook G4 and whenever I boot it, it freezes after about a minute of running it. I need this installed, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with the DVD Live install.

I used the following command to stop the [freezing](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCKnownIssues):

boot: `live-nosplash video=ofonly radeon.agpmode=-1`

The option does not stay after a reboot, so, after the installation you need the following.

boot: `Linux video=ofonly radeon.agpmode=-1`

To [make the option permanent](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#How_do_I_make_a_yaboot_parameter_permanent.3F) you need to edit /etc/yaboot.conf

Look for the line:

`append="quiet splash"`

and change it to:

`append="quiet splash radeon.agpmode=-1"`